# Spark: Streaming json to parquet

Tags: json, apache-spark, parquet

How to convert json to parquet in streaming with Spark?
Acutually i have to ssh from a server, recieve a big json file, convert it to parquet, and upload it on hadoop.
I there a way to do this in a pipelined way?
They are backup files so I have a directory with a predefined amount of files that don't change in size in time

Something like:

```
scp host /dev/stdout | spark-submit myprogram.py | hadoop /dir/
```

edit:
Actually I'm working on this:

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="Test")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec.", "gzip")
#Since i couldn't get the stdio, went for a pipe:
with open("mypipe", "r") as o:
        while True:
                line = o.readline()
                print "Processing: " + line
                lineRDD = sc.parallelize([line])
                df = sqlContext.jsonRDD(lineRDD)
                #Create and append
                df.write.parquet("file:///home/user/spark/test", mode="append")
print "Done."
```

This is working fine, but the resulting parquet is very large (280kb for 4 lines 2 columns json). Any improvements?

Comment: Is it only *one* file? Or is it a stream of files that you need to fetch from ssh (or maybe a shared folder..)?

Comment: There are multiple files, but I need to process them separetly.

Comment: yeah, but is it a stream or do you know exactly the amount of files? Are these files constantly being written (as a stream) to this/these folder/s? Maybe new files are being added every X seconds ... (?)

Comment: Ah, they are backup files so I have a directory with a predefined amount of files that don't change in size in time.

Comment: Ok, good. (you can update your question so that others know it as well) I would say that first of all you don't need Spark Streaming - unless you want to make it more complicated, of course. Considering that they are predefined, could you somehow you copy such files to HDFS before running the spark job? Maybe with a simple script fetch -> write.

Comment: @Markon Of course i can! But I would like to see if there is a more efficent way to copy one time these files, because there are many of them and they are big in size. So yes I can, but seems not reasonable to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I managed to resolve this using the .pipe() method.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=pipe#pyspark.RDD.pipe